# Logic function with range & results

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to create a logic function in Excel where I can look at a range of data and if the argument contains text in each cell then the return should be "x", if contains text in 50% of the cells through 75% then "y", if 0% > 50% then "z".

This is my current function:

```
 IF(A4:P4 = "*t*","Complete",IF(A4:P4 = "","Pending","Incomplete"))
```

Comment: what about >75% and < 100%? Does that count as "Complete too?

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment perhaps try this version:

`=LOOKUP(COUNTA(A4:P4)/COLUMNS(A4:P4),{0,50,75,100}/100,{"incomplete","50 to 75","pending","complete"})`

that will give **incomplete** up to 50%, "50 to 75" for 50% up to 75% and **pending** for 75% and above......except for 100% which wil be **complete** - adjust as required

Comment: Thank you! Complete = 100% complete, anything less would be "Pending"

Comment: I adjusted my formula, see above